# trying to access self inside a lambda function

Tags: rust

I am using evalexpr crate but I assume this is a general failure

To use evalexpr you set up a context that has variables and functions that can be used in evaluating an expression. One function needs to access the self of the containing struct

Here is the code

```
 impl Debugger {
   pub fn evaluate(&self, expr: &str) -> Result<u16> {
        let mut context = HashMapContext::new();
        context.set_value(
            "ac".to_string(),
            evalexpr::Value::Int(Cpu::read_ac() as i64),
        )?;
        context.set_value(
            "xr".to_string(),
            evalexpr::Value::Int(Cpu::read_xr() as i64),
        )?;
        context.set_value(
            "yr".to_string(),
            evalexpr::Value::Int(Cpu::read_yr() as i64),
        )?;
        context.set_value(
            "sp".to_string(),
            evalexpr::Value::Int(Cpu::read_sp() as i64),
        )?;
        context.set_value(
            "pc".to_string(),
            evalexpr::Value::Int(Cpu::read_pc() as i64),
        )?;
        context.set_function(
            "#".to_string(),
            Function::new(|arg| {
                let arg = arg.as_int()?;
                if arg > u16::MAX as i64 {
                    return Err(evalexpr::EvalexprError::WrongFunctionArgumentAmount {
                        expected: RangeInclusive::new(0, 0xffff),
                        actual: arg as usize,
                    });
                }
                let word = Cpu::read_word(arg as u16);
                Ok(evalexpr::Value::Int(word as i64))
            }),
        )?;

        context.set_function(
            "sym".to_string(),
            Function::new(|arg| {
                let arg = arg.as_string()?;

                if let Some(sym) = self.symbols.get(&arg) {
                    return Ok(evalexpr::Value::Int(*sym as i64));
                }
                Err(evalexpr::EvalexprError::CustomMessage(format!(
                    "Symbol {} not found",
                    arg
                )))
            }),
        )?;
        eval_int_with_context_mut(expr, &mut context)
            .map_err(|e| anyhow!(e))
            .map(|v| v as u16)
       
    }
```

all works fine except for the last function definition. It needs to access `self.symbols` (a HashMap).

The compiler complains:

```
  --> src\expr.rs:49:13
   |
10 |       pub fn evaluate(&self, expr: &str) -> Result<u16> {
   |                       -----
   |                       |
   |                       `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
   |                       let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
49 | /             Function::new(move |arg| {
50 | |                 let arg = arg.as_string()?;
51 | |
52 | |                 if let Some(sym) = self.symbols.get(&arg) {
...  |
58 | |                 )))
59 | |             }),
   | |              ^
   | |              |
   | |______________`self` escapes the method body here
   |                argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

I can make it work  by doing

```
        let symbols = self.symbols.clone();
        context.set_function(
            "sym".to_string(),
            Function::new(move |arg| {
                let arg = arg.as_string()?;

                if let Some(sym) = symbols.get(&arg) {
                    return Ok(evalexpr::Value::Int(*sym as i64));
                }
                Err(evalexpr::EvalexprError::CustomMessage(format!(
                    "Symbol {} not found",
                    arg
                )))
            }),
        )?;
```

but thats a very expensive operation (duplicating the symbol table on every call)

Comment: The trait bounds of the function passed to `Function::new` require it to own the data as well as be `Send` and `Sync` so it's going to be impossible to get it to work with your data structure as is. If cloning the symbols table is too expensive you could try putting the symbols inside an `Arc` which would make cloning cheap. It would be a good idea to benchmark though because depending on the workload just doing a dirty clone might be faster: https://blocklisted.github.io/blog/arc_str_vs_string_is_it_really_faster/